# Required "The statutes of an association" in Spanish visa

Tags: visa, spain, paperwork, documentation

I have a brother who was invited by a charity organization in Spain, he has all the documents, but one is not known what it refers to: It is named: "copia de los estatutos de la entidad". What does it refer to exactly? Which legal body it should come from in Spain?

Comment: There are (at least here in the US) two documents that contain "rules" or "statutes" of an entity. In corporate law, for instance, there's the "Articles of Incorporation" which when filed with the government actually creates the entity, and there are the "Bylaws," the internal (to the entity) rules that control how the entity operates. I don't know if the visa application here wants one, or the other, or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the literal meaning. They need the statutes (probably the constituting ones) of the charitable organization, that is, the official rules of the association. The organization should be able to help him with this.